# How to validate a regex to ensure that it does NOT match another regex in php?

Tags: php, regex

I have a situation where the end user is allowed to enter an arbitrary regex expression (php pcre). EG: `^[a-zA-Z]foo[0-9]{3}$`

I need to 'validate' this regex both for:

1. accuracy (that it will not cause an error when executed) and
2. to ensure that the regex will not allow a string that matches the following pattern to be matched: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]$`

What is a good way (ideally in php) to perform the 2 validations above?

Note: I am not able to at runtime to simply use both regex expressions for matching each string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's impossible. PCRE is a turing complete language, so in essence you're trying to [solve the halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). The only way to do it is to simply run the PCRE and check for errors.

Comment: Right.  The best you can do here, I'm afraid, is when given a user-generated PCRE, run it against a test string just to make sure it doesn't error out.